# Need Assistance on getting LINK ID using Regular Expressions?

Tags: vb.net, url, expression

I got this **url** for example "http://www.yellowpages.com/manhattan-beach-ca/mip/marriott-manhattan-beach-4933923?lid=185795402"

I want to get the **last digit numbers** and the rest could be anything.

I need a format like this "http://www.yellowpages.com/anything.... lid=***randomdigitnumbers***" or as long as i get those numbers.

My knowledge is very poor in this regex thing so please guys help me.

the following did not work

```
Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("http://www.yellowpages.com/.*lid=d*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim m As Match = r.Match(txt)
    If (m.Success) Then
        Dim int1 = m.Groups(1)
        MsgBox("(" + int1.ToString() + ")" + "")
    End If
```

thank you in advance

Comment: It'd be easier to simply use string functions to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regular Expressions for this is a bit of overkill, IMO.

You could accomplish the same thing using string functions:

```
Dim url As String = "http://www.yellowpages.com/manhattan-beach-ca/mip/marriott-manhattan-beach-4933923?lid=185795402"

Dim queryString As String = url.SubString(url.IndexOf("?"), url.Length - url.IndexOF("?"))

Dim nameValuePairs As String() = queryString.Split("=")

Dim lid As String = nameValuePairs(1)
```

This is off the top of my head, so you may need to tweak it a bit.  The basic concept is to the portion of the URL after the ? (the query string), and then split it on the = sign, taking the second element of the resulting array (the value).

Also, if the query string has more than one name value pair, they'll be separated by `&`, so you'll need to split on the ampersand (`&`) first, then the equal signs.

Comment: oh, right! kind of done the same thing just a while ago. but thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just find `lid=` and get everything after that:

```
Dim url As String = "http://www.yellowpages.com/manhattan-beach-ca/mip/marriott-manhattan-beach-4933923?lid=185795402"
Dim lidIndex As Integer = url.IndexOf("lid=") + "lid=".Length
Dim lid As Integer = url.Substring(lidIndex)
```

Comment: +1 for a shorter solution than mine - though it will have the same problem my solution would if there's more than one parameter in the query string.

Comment: thanks I think I've done the same thing. Although I really want to get it by regex I think I'll get it some other time